# How can I change sound theme from terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, sound, themes

I am creating an automated script that sets up my OS by itself. I need it to change sound too, what is the command for that? Currently, I know that:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name yaru
```

is for shell;

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme applications
```

is for applications and so on. What is the command for sound? The option is there in the gnome tweaks program, so there must be a way to do it from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name 'yourinstalledsoundtheme'
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, for some reason i found it really hard to find

Comment: yup.. are you using 19.04??

Comment: yes i am using 19.04